# IOS - Firebase Dynamic Link Opens the app but shows text buttons on STATUS BAR

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-dynamic-links

Problem 1: So I am using the Firebase dynamiclink and works fine. My problem is I want to hide the textButton on my status bar (DONOT WANT TO HIDE THE WHOLE STATUS BAR, the buttons) whenever the app opens on dynamic links. See photo.

Problem 2: I accidentally tapped the goo.gl above and now the app is not opening on the dynamic link. It goes to safari instead. how to bring it back to normal?

[image: THIS IS THE PHOTO, PLEASE SEE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: I do not believe this is possible. It would be great if so, but as far as I know it is enforced by iOS.

Problem 2: paste the URL into the Notes app, long-press on it, and select **Open in [App]**

Comment: I love your answer mate. Made research too. You are right!

Comment: My pleasure! Glad it helped :)